# xmlrpcmsg::serialize() doesn't put params into serialized payload

Tags: php, xml, serialization, xml-rpc

We use the php xmlrpc library to do xml rpc requests to an email provider.

These have always worked however when testing these features on a new environment (php 5.6 instead of 5.3) it seems that the `xmlrpcmsg` won't build in the parameter values when calling xmlrpcmsg::serialize(). Even though the params are clearly there when I var_dump the object.

The way I include the library is through including `xmlrpc.inc` (// Copyright (c) 1999,2000,2002 Edd Dumbill.) although I can't find any documentation which may tell me about any extensions that may be required or php version compatibility.

Example:

```
$this->msg = new xmlrpcmsg(
                    "contact.transactional", array(
                        // carer details
                        new xmlrpcval(
                            array(
                                "carer_id" => new xmlrpcval($data['Carer_ID'], "string"),
                                "email" => new xmlrpcval($data['CarerEmail'], "string"),
                            ), "struct"
                        ),
                        // campaign_id to be launched
                        new xmlrpcval($trigger['trigger_id'], "int"),
                        // transactional data to be passed into email template
                        new xmlrpcval(
                            array(
                                "carer_id" => new xmlrpcval($data['Carer_ID'], "int"), 
                                "baby_id" => new xmlrpcval($data['Baby_ID'], "string"),
                                "carer_email" => new xmlrpcval($data['CarerEmail'], "string"), 
                            ), "struct"
                        ),
                    )
                );
```

When I `var_dump` `$this->msg->serialize()` on my local system / the already live server

```
<methodcall>
<methodname>contact.transactional</methodname>
<params>
    <param>
    <value>
        <struct>
            <member>
                <name>email</name>
                <value>
                    <string>adam+testest@testest.co.uk</string>
                </value>
            </member>
        </struct>
    </value>
    <param>
    <value>
        <int>17458</int>
    </value>
    <param>
    <value>
        <struct>
            <member>
                <name>carer_id</name>
                <value>
                    <string>654321</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>baby_id</name>
                <value>
                    <string>123456</string>
                </value>
            </member>
            <member>
                <name>carer_email</name>
                <value>
                    <string>adam+testest@testest.co.uk</string>
                </value>
            </member>
        </struct>
    </value>
</params>
</methodcall>
```

When I `var_dump` `$this->msg->serialize()` on the new testing server

```
<methodcall>
<methodname>contact.transactional</methodname>
<params>
    <param>
    <value></value>
    <param>
    <value></value>
    <param>
    <value></value>
</params>
</methodcall>
```

Comment: That looks like a userland library not the standard PHP [XMLRPC extension](http://php.net/xmlrpc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to update the library to the latest version [phpxmlrpc at github](https://github.com/gggeek/phpxmlrpc)